# Can't connect Django and my react native app... [Network request failed]

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, rest

I can't get a response from the rest API that I have created to my React Native Applications. Eventhough, I run django server and the rest api is still running, but I cant get response from rest API. The request in working on postman and I can get response there but not in react native app.I have attached my code below. Kindly, go through it

**React Native Code**

```
 useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/movies/')
      .then(res => console.log(res.json))

      .catch(err => console.log(err));

     
  }, []);
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for movietracker project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'v23d&&w#*&g4q+mse7nbby4rms79(r7@feg&j1d*wf=3vq8)&4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'api'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   
]
 


ROOT_URLCONF = 'movietracker.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'movietracker.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# CORS Config
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

Comment: Try to add this https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ in your Django project. I guess you are having the CORS issue. you should also add 'corsheaders', in your installed_apps

Comment: In your package.json did you set the proxy field?

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation (https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/), you should also add corsheaders to your installed_apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'corsheaders',
        'api'
    ]
```

And also add

```
# Corsheaders settings
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    '*'
)
```

Comment: I added as you mentioned. But, I am getting the same error

Comment: Can you put this 'corsheaders' avobe the api? and restart you django server

Comment: Yes, I have given as u said

Comment: You need to add this too.  In your project.                                                   
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    '*'
)

Comment: I added thi. Still, cant get the response ` CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:8000',
]`

Comment: I guess you should use double quotes, ["http://localhost:8000",]

Comment: CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8000'] ...Got the same result

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I solved it.**
1 - open command prompt and type this:

```
ipconfig
```

Then copy paste your IPv4 Address eg ('182.167.2.65')

2 - Add the following line of code to your settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS += '182.167.2.65'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # Change it in production and specify your own origins
```

3 - Run server as follows:

```
py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

4 - In react now fetch to this direction:

```
'182.167.2.65' ## This direction is just an example (put your IPv4)
```